# Is there a way to configure ArcMap to persist the HTML popup window size?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, tools

I'm specifically asking for when the "Display HTML formatting" is configured as "As a table of the visible fields.", but I think all options behave the same way.

My users click the HTML Popup tool[image], click the feature on the map to display the HTML popup window, and resize the window until the get the desired size.  If they close that window, and repeat the steps...the windows reverts back to the original size and they must resize each time.  They feel, and I agree with them, that the window should open up to be the same size as when it was closed.  Is this an ArcMap configuration?  Or is there a registry value?  Is there a way to affect window size if you format using an XSL template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [ESRI forum thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=271029) which deals with this issue. It can be apparently worked around by using XSL templates and html IFRAMEs. The thread is quite old, so I am not sure if the workaround still applies to ArcGIS 10.. might as well be completely useless by now.

---

See [Jay's expanded answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/4612/115) with screenshots.

Comment: I'm not using a URL, but I left out the src for the IFRAME and it still works!

Comment: Ah, so it's just the presence of an IFRAME inside the popup window which does the trick. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 7):

**Expanded answer based on [@petr k.'s](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/434/petr-k) accepted [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4604/is-there-a-way-to-configure-arcmap-to-persist-the-html-popup-window-size/4606#4606).**

---

The example in the ESRI forum is using a URL, but I was able to knock out the src attribute and set the height to 0 in order to control my width: `<iframe width="500" height="0"></iframe>`   In my case, I'm not concerned about the height of the window.

In ArcGIS 10, I selected the "As a formatted page based on an XSL template" and then `Load`-->`Load default template` to get something to tweak.

[image]
In the XSL find the `<body>` and `<table>` tags:

```
<body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">
<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
```

...and put the `<iframe width="500" height="0"></iframe>` in between them:

[image]

Comment: Great! Will be very helpful to other people. +1

Comment: This works, but there are limits. Using ArcMap 10.1 under Windows 7, it appears that the html popup cannot cover the clicked feature. So, if the feature is centered in the screen, you're limited to a bit less than half the size of the map view and iframe width values beyond that will still leave you with a popup that does not show all of your content and must be manually expanded each time it opens. This is kind of an odd limitation that produces a rather artificial constraint on usable html popup sizes. It would be nice if it were possible to override this...